# Remove spacing between theorem environments in hebrew article

Tags: spacing, lyx, hebrew

I'm making a cheat-sheet for an upcoming exam. It must be 1 A4 page (double sided). I've set the size of everything to tiny (it took quite a lot of effort) but now I have a serious problem with spacing - there is an awful amount of space between different environments (theorems, lemmas, definitions, claims and proofs) that I use (in the 'Hebrew Article' document type).

I tried to solve it and found the following solution - to put the following code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
\thm@preskip=0pt  \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother
```

I added it and now the preamble looks like this:

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol} 

\date{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\RLmulticolcolumns
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\tiny}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\tiny}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\tiny}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{claim}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{remark}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{corollary}{\tiny} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\tiny} 

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
\thm@preskip=0pt  \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother
```

However it still doesn't fix the spacing issue, and it still has plenty of spaces:
[image: look at those horrendous spaces]

I'm now hopeless and (since I spent way too much time on this instead of studying for other exams) would appreciate any sort help.

EDIT: minimized into 1 page - here https://goo.gl/3q1l7L

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. For more information, read http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: https://goo.gl/3q1l7L here

Comment: did you read the link? That is not a minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the command \vspace{} with a negative length argument, each time you need to remove an unused space.

This is not obviously the best solution for such an issue, but if you don't find a better one, you should resort to it.

Comment: The thing is there are at least a dozen places where it's a big space (and many places that could have less), and I haven't even finished writing everything. Will resort to it if nothing else comes up, thanks.